# Does the Rune of the Monk's healing bonus stack with Aquatic Benevolence?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The 6-piece bonus for the [Superior Rune of the Monk](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rune_of_the_Monk) grants +10% outgoing heal effectiveness to allies.

The Elementalist trait [Aquatic Benevolence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Aquatic_Benevolence) increases healing done to allies by 25%.

Do these two bonuses stack to increase healing done to allies by 35%, or does Aquatic Benevolence override the bonus from the Rune?

Comment: Yes, but not on yourself, only on _other_ allies (AB doesn't affect your own healing, see your link). Good question, as I haven't seen the difference between straight-up Healing Power and something that doesn't increase your stat directly but "improves effectiveness" explained very well anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple "outgoing heal effectiveness" effects will stack additively. If you combine Aquatic Benevolence with Rune of the Monk, outgoing healing will be increased by 35%.

I did some tests on this in Heart of the Mists by equipping a Rune of the Grove and traiting 0/0/0/6/0 for 1397 Healing Power, then observing the effects of my [Soothing Mist](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Soothing_Mist) on myself and others.

The base effectiveness of Soothing Mist was 150 HP/second on both myself and others. When I swapped the Rune of the Grove for a Rune of the Monk, the effect on others increased to 165 HP/sec. Adding the Aquatic Benevolence trait increased it to 203 HP/sec.

These numbers work out increases of 10% and 35% over the baseline of 150.